# CloudKit Dashboard insufficient privileges

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, icloud, cloudkit

I can't access the CloudKit dashboard at `https://icloud.developer.apple.com/dashboard/`.  I keep getting the error `Insufficient privileges You Apple ID does not have the required privileges to access any iCloud Container.  Please contact your team administrator for the necessary privileges.` I'm getting this error even though I'm the only team member.  Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Does your Certs & Provisioning dashboard already list one or more iCloud containers?

Comment: @WardBekker I have a Cloud Container identifier setup.  There isn't an option to setup a Cert or a Profile for a Cloud Container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the 'Insufficient Privileges" error after I created an AppID & a Container, but I didn't have the Container selected in XCode.  Its very misleading.  I specified the container and it fixed the issue.

Make sure you - 
1. Have CloudKit Checked
2. Have the Container you just created checked (it doesn't do this automatically)
[image]

Comment: it turns out that setting up the container through the developer portal isn't good enough.  If you don't select these options in Xcode, it doesn't wire everything together.

Answer (score 0):

What solved this issue for me was this answer, actually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34215291/4075379

My App ID had a yellow warning saying "configurable" in CloudKit. I configured it, and had to then update my provisioning profile (simply edit the provisioning profile, save, download, and open), and then the I could successfully open the CloudKit Dashboard.

Hope this still helps someone.