# How to add iCloud entitlement to app ID?

Tags: ios

How can I add iCloud entitlement to app ID? I wants to use just key-value storage in iCloud. I have enabled iCloud by editing my existing iOS app ID. Then, generated new provisioning profile, installed it in XCode. I added my app bundle ID in `com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier`. XCode gives me warning that `Add the iCloud entitlement to your app ID`. I dont know where I have done wrong. Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try just enabling it directly in Xcode?

Comment: Don't we require to enable iCloud in our app ID on member center?

Comment: Yes but most likely you're using a Xcode-controlled provisioning profile which you can't edit in the developer portal, which means you have to inform Xcode of the iCloud entitlement so it updates the profile correctly. You can do that in your project screen.

Comment: Oh, So which means we dont require enabling iCloud on member center, just enabling it in XCode6 solves our purpose?

Comment: You'll want to enable it in the member center too, especially if you want it to work with Adhoc provisioned devices (and Store releases too), but I *think* Xcode just takes care of that for you now.

Comment: Also, Whenever I click Fix Issue button under iCloud capability window, it automatically invalidates my active provisioning profile. Can you tell me why it makes it invalid everytime and how to solve this issue?

Comment: I think it just does that. Is it causing issues if it does that?

Comment: I dont know if it is causing any issue, I am getting `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: <app ID> has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement`.

Comment: Is it fine to use invalid provisioning profile in XCode?

Answer (score 3):

As it says, login to Apple member center and configure app's identifier.

[image]

Select the iCloud container (if you can't select, create one)

[image]

PS: I can only post 2 images now, so I can't show you more details.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that could help is updating provision profiles (cause after adding new capabilities, you have to do it)

To do that you have to go to Apple member centre -> Provision profiles (All). And here, if some profiles have a yellow exclamation mark, choose it, click "Edit", and then "Download". After downloading open it. That will help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to void the error "Internal error ...." you have to:

1. Register any device on your Apple Developer under Certificates IDs and profiles
2. Connect your phone or your iPad and register it
3. Go back to your application
4. Click fix