# Using CloudKit with a free Apple Account

Tags: xcode, cloudkit

I am building an app and I am trying to enable CloudKit in xcode, in captabilites.
I am getting some issues like:
"Add the iCloud feature to your app ID"
"Add the iCloud containers to your app ID".

I tried to login in Apple member center and configure app's identifier, but I cannot find the "Identifiers" or the "App IDs" there. Such as I read in here: [How to add iCloud entitlement to app ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804558/how-to-add-icloud-entitlement-to-app-id)

I don't have a Apple (ID) paid account. Do I have to have a paid account to use Cloudkit?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to be a registered developer to use cloudKit, you cannot blame Apple, it must be costing a small fortune to maintain it. See this page. https://developer.apple.com/icloud/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to have paid account to enable or test the CloudKit and reach the CloudKit Dashboard.